# Syncfusion RTE Keyboard

Tags: asp.net, rich-text-editor, syncfusion, rte

I am using RTE from Syncfusion in ASP.NET.

I have a problem with keyboard shortcuts and keystrokes. When I try to paste (to replace) on a selected text it does not work and does not show any error either. When I paste a large text portion in the RTE it only works if I empty it first. And after the first paste it does not allow further text after that. In some places when text is already available, it does not allow more text to be added only space.

Has it gone crazy? Tested in 3 browsers so far, Chrome, Edge and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have checked the reported issues with RTE sample. unfortunately, we could not reproduce the issue. We have attached a video demo for your reference. Please refer to the following link for Video: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/133567/ze/RTECopypaste-1148901235

We have attached a sample in the below link:
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/133567/ze/RTE-541310972

Please check if the reported issue is reproduced at your end. If yes, then provide us a sample or video exhibiting the issue at your end, this will help us debug the issue locally and provide solution.

Comment: The problem was from my end. The property of MaxLength by default is 7000 which was causing this. I have allowed more. Can I know what is the Max Length of MaxLength.